# Adding log4perl to windows server 2008 running perl32

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, perl

Yes I know, It's a really weird configuration but I can't do anything to change it. I wonder if it's possible to run log4perl on Windows 2008 64 bit system running Perl 32 bit.
Does any one have a clue on how to install it.

Update: 
Server isn't connected to the network, CPAN isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2):

From cpan,
open cpan console then :

```
install Log::Log4perl
```

Comment: Recursive dependency detected:
    Log::Log4perl
 => M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.34.tar.gz
 => Test::More
 => M/MS/MSCHWERN/Test-Simple-0.98.tar.gz
 => ExtUtils::MakeMaker
 => M/MS/MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.62.tar.gz
 => File::Spec
 => S/SM/SMUELLER/PathTools-3.33.tar.gz
 => Scalar::Util
 => G/GB/GBARR/Scalar-List-Utils-1.23.tar.gz
 => Test::More.
Cannot continue.

Comment: Install each dependency before, by hand.

Comment: there is no internet connection in the server. I wonder if I can prepare the Binaries in advance. I need to put these binaries in several server. Some of them already running.

Comment: so you have to download and install by hand all required packages, you can search and download them from here : http://www.cpan.org/